# Help identifying capacitor-like symbol with a bracket or "U" shape on one side

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I came across a circuit diagram online which I want to modify for a circuit I am designing but I wasn't sure about one of the components in the diagram.

The component is labeled as CP has a value of Farads so I'm assuming it's just a capacitor but after searching around I couldn't confirm if it was or not

**Is it some kind of special component or just an odd circuit symbol for a regular capacitor?**

[image: Close up of the symbol in an circuit]

(whole circuit: https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/temperature/files/rtdmodule.png)

Comment: It's just an electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Just an electrolytic, the "cup" denoting negative.

Comment: It is one of several different symbols used for electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/01049.png This is more Google-worthy than a question.

Comment: The "CP" is an acronym (C.P.) for "Capacitor, Polarised", basically a normal electrolytic capacitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a symbol for an electrolytic capacitor. The cup shape is meant to imply the type of capacitors that are often manufactured in an aluminum can.